# external libraries in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have my directory structure set up as follows:

```
application
  controllers
  models
  libraries
  views
  etc
library
  codeigniter_1_7_2
  codeigniter_1_7_1
public_html
  images
  scripts
```

This has worked well for me, and I like having the codeigniter "master" files off in their own library.  A quick switch in the index.php file and I can swap between different versions.

One thing that I WANT to do is when using something from Zend (like the search/lucene class) is to put the Zend directory under the main "library" folder. It's recommended that it go in my application/libraries folder, but then often when I search for a piece of code in my application I get a huge set of results from the large Zend library that I have to scroll through. It also really doesn't belong there given how I've set up my directory structure.

My problem is that if I try and put zend in the /library folder, I have to use php's require_once (I assume) and then I get permission errors.

If the zend library is at /application/libraries/Zend, this works:

```
$this->load->library('zend', 'Zend/Search/Lucene');
$this->load->library('zend');
$this->zend->load('Zend/Search/Lucene');
```

If the zend library is at /library/Zend this does NOT work:
`require_once('../library/Zend');`
The directory route is correct there, I just get a "permission denied" error.

Has someone else had this problem or figured out a nice easy way to set up their external libraries similar to how I'd like to do it?